Filters roots radicle stack, sage, blade, bedrock, wordpress where I need to register filters for plugins
I already spent a lot of time looking for this answer. So based on the documentation I supposed to create a file under app called filters.php and then I can write my filters inside. So did, but they were not working. I did more research and found users having the same issue and they just add the  NAMESPACE ( magic constant ) inside the filter function call and it worked for them but not for me, so I'm quite of wondering what I am doing wrong.
So currently that's the way my filters.php looks like:
<?php

/**
 * Theme filters.
 */

namespace App;

/**
 * Contact Form 7 Custom filters
 *
 * @return string
 */

add_filter('wpcf7_validate_text*', __NAMESPACE__ , 'custom_text_validation_filter', 20, 2);

function custom_text_validation_filter($result, $tag) {
    if ($tag->is_required() && 'text' === $tag->basetype && isset($_POST[$tag->name])) {
        $field_value = $_POST[$tag->name];

        $re = '/^[^\p{N}][\p{L}]*/i';

        if (!preg_match($re, $field_value, $matches)) {
            $result->invalidate($tag, "This is not a valid string");
        }
    }

    return $result;
}


And my projekt structure looks like:

Thank you in advance for the help...
